# How to remove the Override checkbox from TFS 2008 check ins with policy failures

Tags: tfs, policy, checkin

In short, I want to stop our devs from overriding policy failures on check in.

If I can't do that then I want to modify the Reason text box to look for something more than just a single character being typed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot be done in a supported way I'm afraid - but you can sign yourself up for email alerts (or alert to a distribution list) when an override is performed and use that to make sure any unwanted behavior is quickly stamped out in the devs.

The easiest way to set up an email alert on check-in policy override is to use the Alerts editor that is installed as part of the [Team Foundation Server 2008 Power Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/bb980963.aspx).

To find out how to add the alert, take a look at the following blog post:

- [Policy Override Email Alerts](http://www.woodwardweb.com/vsts/policy_override.html)

Comment: Grr..  I wonder if 2010 will "fix" this.  They really should rename "Policies" to "Completely Ignorable Guidelines".  The problem is we already have so many alerts etc that it's nearly impossible to wade through the shear volume of emails to figure out what someone is trying to get away with.  It would be much better to have enforceable policies.

Comment: I'm not aware of this being a feature in TFS2010 - it certainly isn't in the beta 1. If you want to go to http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio and add it as a feature then now is the time.